# How Can I Import From Outside a File?

Tags: reactjs

im trying to import from a file called "data.json", however I am getting this error: Module not found: Can't resolve './src/data/data.json' in ...src/components/Table'
Anyone know how to help?

My code:

`import {data} from "./src/data/data.json";`

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

if Table is folder and you are importing in a  file inside it then try this:

```
import * as data from "../../data/data.json";
```

if Table is a js file then try this:

```
import * as data from "../../data/data.json";
```